# How does OpenClover count complexity for method?

Tags: java, clover

I have a method in a class:

```
    public boolean tryFile() throws IOException {
        File file = File.createTempFile("test", "dat");
        file.deleteOnExit();
        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
            fos.write(20);
        }
        return file.exists();
    }
```

According OpenClover documentation:

> Method Complexity
>
> Cyclomatic complexity of a single method. It's calculated as follows:
>
> empty method complexity == 1
>   simple statement complexity == 0
>   switch block complexity == number of case statements
>   try catch block complexity == number of catch statements
>   ternary expression complexity == 1
>   boolean expression complexity == number of && or || in expression

In report generated by OpenClover (version 4.4.1) the complexity for this method equals 3. Why? How it was counted?

PS. For example in JaCoCo report I see Ctx=1 for this method.

Answer (score 0):

Try-with-resources is effectively syntactic sugar. There are a few catches and conditional blocks generated. See [JLS section 14.20.3.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3).

Clover doesn't know try-with-resources was used. It's probably looking at an AST which has already converted the try-with-resources to the equivalent try-catch-finally. This means there is no trace of that specific language construct, and there is no way to have a special case for it, even if the Clover developers wanted to have one.

Comment: No. Clover never looks at byte code. JaCoCo is looking at bytecode. By the way JaCoCo have a filter for this case and Cyclomatic complexity (CTX) in JaCoCo report for this method is 1.

Comment: @AlekseyUlasevich Bytecode was a mistake, sorry. I don't know the implementations details of Clover obviously but they are probably not literally parsing the source directly, but via an AST and there's nothing to say that the AST parser hasn't already converted try-with-resources into the equivalent try-catch.